# Unwanted logical variable in Prolog output

Tags: prolog

I have to do a Prolog homework for College and I'm mostly done, but i keep getting a `_G` variable in the output.

We need to compare a List - `L` -  to a regular term - `K` -, and, if the item in the list is bigger than the term, add it to another list - `R` -.

This is my Code

```
teilliste_grK([],0,[]).
teilliste_grK([],_,[_]).
teilliste_grK([H|T],K,L) :-
   (  H > K
   -> L = [H|R],
      teilliste_grK(T,K,R)
   ;  L = R,
      teilliste_grK(T,K,R)
   ).

?- teilliste_grK([12,4,1,34,5,45],9,R).
```

It works but instead of `R = [12,34,45]` I get `R = [12,34,45, _Gxxx]`. I just don't know why.

Comment: Examine your fact `teilliste_grK([], _, [_]).`. What does it mean, semantcally? The `_Gxxx` comes from a `_`.

Comment: I overdid it... after editing it to `teilliste_grK([],_,[])` it now works fine. The problem without the line was getting false everytime because it "redid" `L` backwards. So because of `L` beeing empty till the recursion is done i don't need the second `[_]` bracket?

Comment: The term `[_]` is a list with one, anonymous element. The term `[]` is an empty list. They are different. If the semantic meaning of your fact indicates an empty list, then `[]` is correct. If the fact indicates a list of one, anonymous element, then `[_]` is correct. :) Note also that if you have the fact, `teilliste_grK([], _, []).`, then the fact, `teilliste_grK([], 0, []).` is redundant since `teilliste_grK([], _, []).` will match `teilliste_grK([], 0, []).` with `_` instantiated as `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those answers. Still trying to get the bigger picture of Prolog after years (in school) of oop.

Comment: at the moment, you are not comparing just any prolog terms, but numbers or arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct first clause of your predicate is a combination of the two clauses you have on top now.

First one insists the *K* is 0: you don't want this. Second one insists on having one extra variable at the end of the second list: you don't want this either.

Just ignore the *K* and close the list:

```
foo([], _, []).
```